# Django objects filter hurge array of integers

Tags: django, filter, bulk

I would like to get many order numbers, example:

```
order_nrs = range(123460000, 123461500)

orders = Order.objects.filter(order_number__in=order_nrs)
```

In reality the order nrs are unsorted and the range is between 10000000 and 70000000

But this is returning the following error: 
DatabaseError: too many SQL variables

I could not find a correct solution for this problem, I have tried the bulk_in, but order_number is not the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better way for that, but this one should work:

```
order_nrs = range(123460000, 123461500)
list = Order.objects.filter(order_number__lt=max(order_nrs), order_number__gt=min(order_nrs))
```

Or

```
list = Order.objects.filter(order_number__range=order_nrs)
```

Comment: Thx, the first one is working proper. The example of me it's a nice range, but in in reality the order_nrs are unsorted and range between 10000000 and 70000000. The request of my programm need to handle max 1500 order nrs per time.